# Qt download attribute support

Tags: javascript, html, qt, qtwebkit

I am using Qt 5.2 and QWebView widget to display the web content.
How to handle HTML5 "download" attribute (client side downloading ) in QWebView ? Is there any signal emitted ?

Below is the reference HTML.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>    
<body>
<a id="my_id" download="hello.txt" href="data:text/csv,abc">download   
txt</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure but "QWebPage"s `downloadRequested()` signal may be emitted. Another signal that can be helpful is `unsupportedContent()` signal of QWebPage.

QWebView has a pointer to it's QWebPage, `webView.page()`. You can connect those signals like this:

```
connect(webView->page(), SIGNAL(downloadRequested(QNetworkRequest)), this, SLOT(yourDownloadSlot(QNetworkRequest)));
connect(webView->page(), SIGNAL(unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(yourUnsupportedContentSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
```

Comment: This is only helpful when we download the file from the server and click on "Save Link...". I have checked that. but download attribute is like client side download.. as we already have data @ client side and we want to download it. How to do that ?

Comment: Did you try the `unsupportedContent()` signal. Because the `href` attribute is not a link, so webkit will not be able to handle that request and call unsupportedContent. BTW, I'm just making assumptions.

Comment: I have tried unsupportedContent() signal but it is not getting called..